# How to display an onSubmit that results in a URL in an iframe on the same website?

Tags: html, forms, iframe

- I created a form in which you can enter a text
- With onSubmit, this text creates a URL
- I would like to have this website opened in an iframe on the same page where the form is.
- What I've done:

```html
<form onsubmit= "location.href = 'http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=' + score.value + '&ftab=FeedbackAsSeller'; return false; target="eBay";">
<input type="text" name="score" placeholder="Copy Seller ID here"> <input type="submit" value="Enter/Click">
</form> 
    
<iframe name="eBay"src="" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
```

- I supposed that the target attribute would do the trick, but I still get redirected to the generated URL. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: your form onsubmit is changing the whole page url with the location href, your score.value probably wasn';t getting a value as you had no id set and not the right way of getting the value, document.getElementById('score').value would've worked if you had set id="value" on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put whole code

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Please Rate if it helps</title>
 <!-- PUT A PATH OF JQUERY LIBRARY -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
        function onSubmitCallIt() {
            $("#eBay").attr("src", 'http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=' + score.value + '&ftab=FeedbackAsSeller');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="score" name="score" placeholder="Copy Seller ID here">
        <input type="button" value="Enter/Click" onclick="onSubmitCallIt();">
    </form>
    <iframe id="eBay" name="eBay" src="" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Rate, If it helps...

Comment: yes it works because by default browser take id as varible in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openWin(){
  alert("in func");
 var frame=document.getElementById("iFrame");
var sellID=document.getElementById("score").value;
var win="http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=" + sellID + "&ftab=FeedbackAsSeller";
  frame.src=win;
  alert("done");
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="openWin()">
<input type="text" name="score" id="score" placeholder="Copy Seller ID here"> <input type="submit" value="Enter/Click">
</form> 
    
<iframe name="eBay"id="iFrame" src="" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
```